# Set the EditText ImeActionLabel to custom text?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, keyboard, ime

Currently, I'm looking to change the design of the button that closes the Android keyboard. Currently it looks like: [Basic Android Keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yBFb.png). I want to remove the checkmark and replace it with some text like OK or Done without changing the whole keyboard.

Using `ImeOptions`, I know i can set the `Android.Views.InputMethods.ImeAction` to a default icon, but none of the default icons are what I'm looking for.

Using `SetImeActionLabel("OK", Android.Views.InputMethods.ImeAction.Done)`, I can edit the text that's being shown, but it's only text. I need it to have the green, circular background. If I go with this route, I'm unsure on how I can edit the styles of this `ActionLabel`. Here is a picture for reference: [Android Keyboard with OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xt0Nk.png).

I'm having a lot of trouble finding a similar example or problem and can't exactly solve it myself.

Comment: Did you created a custom entry for that ?

Comment: Yes, this is being done through a custom entry and a custom entry renderer.

Comment: and i guess that you call SetImeActionLabel in OnElementChanged

Answer (score 0):

You cann add shape to it as a background

```
 protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            var newCustomEntryElement = e.NewElement as CustomEntry;
            if (Control == null || newCustomEntryElement == null)
            {
                return;
            }
             Control.ImeOptions = ImeAction.Go;
                Control.SetImeActionLabel("Go", ImeAction.Go);



            var shape = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
            shape.Paint.Color = Android.Graphics.Color.Red;
            shape.Paint.StrokeWidth = 0;
            shape.Paint.SetStyle(Paint.Style.Stroke);
            Control.SetBackground(shape);
        }
```

Comment: Doing this creates the shapes around each Text Entry box instead of around the OK Button to close the keyboard. I like the idea, but I can't figure out how to get it around the IME action button.

Comment: So this will do a shape for all keyboard button ? can you share a screenshot ?

Comment: Not around all the keyboard buttons, but around all the text fields where I would type into. I'm not sure if I can share a screenshot.

Comment: upload the screenshot to any image hosting website and share the link

Comment: Here is an example of what's happening to every text field, using the OvalShape(): https://imgur.com/a/ZVd0aqq

I'm sure it's because I've set the custom renderer to deal with the text fields, but I need a way to access and change the keyboard that pops up.